# How do I reduce the flickering when the form is refreshing?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap

So when ever I hold the left mouse button and draw the rectangle on the form.
The form itself keeps flickering.
I've tried setting the DoubleBuffered property to true, that didnt change anything.
Is there a way to change the refresh rate or something similar?
Because from what I've tried, the example above and 
`SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);`

It doesnt seem to change anything

Here is a gif showing the flickering

https://i.imgur.com/Wa3kmbM.gifv

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //Hide the Form
    this.Hide();
    label1.Visible = false;
    label2.Visible = false;

    //Create the Bitmap (This is an a black bitmap holding just the size.) (Bitmap is mutable)
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

    //Create a graphics object that's ready for alteration. `printscreen` is now a graphics Object
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen);
    //Alter the graphics object which again is the printscreen
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);


    //Create a temporary memory stream for the image
    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //save graphic variable into memory
        printscreen.Save(s, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        //Set the size of the picturebox
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(Width, Height);

        //set the value of the picturebox.Image to an Image.FromStream and load the temp stream
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(s);
    }
    //Show Form
    this.Show();

    //Cross Cursor
    Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //startX is holds the corresponding value of where the mouse is in relation to the pixels of the width
        //for instance, if it's all the way to the right, it holds the value of 1920.
        startX = e.X;
        startY = e.Y;
        selectPen = new Pen(Color.DimGray, 2);
        selectPen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        start = true;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (start)
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        //selectingWidth is equal to how much we have selected from the starting point.
        //Let's say the starting point is 10 and our current mouse position is at 10 then we have selected 0 pixels to the right.
        //However if we move our mouse 10 pixels to the right it means we have selected 10 pixels to the right.
        selectingWidth = e.X - startX;
        selectingHeight = e.Y - startY;

        //if the selectingWidth is less than 0, then set the origin to the current position of the mouse.
        var drawfromX = selectingWidth < 0 ? e.X : startX;
        var drawfromY = selectingHeight < 0 ? e.Y : startY;

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(selectPen,
            drawfromX,
            drawfromY,
            Math.Abs(selectingWidth),
            Math.Abs(selectingHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: A few notes: You could have a Graphics object created only once. I would put the drawing code in the overridden Paint event and just invalidate the PictureBox.

Comment: Why are you calling Refresh all the time for no reason.  That invalidates and forces repaint then and there.   You normally would use Invalidate() though nicer to kittens won’t solve your flicker.   Consider making your own UserControl and paint in an offscreen bitmap.   That results in zero flicker.   Otherwise use WPF

Comment: He __needs one__ Refresh for drawing the (non-persistent) rubber-band rectangle. The 1st one in the move is wrong though - I prefer this `if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))...` over a flag, btw. - PictureBox is already double-buffered by default. The form alone doesn't need it as long as you don't draw on it. It has a double-buffered property exposed, though. - But using the Paint event with the e.Graphics object is preferred. Not flicker there..

Comment: Calling Refresh instead of _Invalidate(false) + OnPaint_ is a recipe for flicker